# How to pass a variable to php page beside this.serialize with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to pass a variable from ajax to php beside the serialize data.

My code will explain what I mean:

```
        $('#update_form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var total = parseFloat($('#total').text()); // This is the var I want to pass
            if($('.check_box:checked').length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"pages/Model/multiple_update.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function()
                    {
                        alert('Data Updated');
                        $('#multiple_update').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        fetch_data();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: `data: { "total": total }`, assuming you don't want to submit any other fields from the form. It'll be accessible as `$_POST["total"]` in the PHP, obviously.

Comment: Yes but how to send it with $(this).serialize() also?

Comment: In that case, see the answer below from RiggsFolly. Bear in mind that if your form already has a field called "total" which gets serialized, then you should either a) do something to make it _not_ serialize that field (e.g. remove its `name` attribute), or b) call this parameter something else e.g. `floatTotal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

serialize() creates a querystring in the format `a=1&b=2` so you could add to it like this

```
var total = parseFloat($('#total').text()); 
var qs = $(this).serialize() + '&total=' + total;
```

and then send that

```
data:qs,
```

Or

```
data:$(this).serialize() + '&total=' + total,
```

Comment: in this case total = undefined

Comment: Then you put it in the wrong place or the calculation for `total` is not right

Comment: I added the total calculation so you see where it should be placed in relation to the calc of total

Comment: No I just tried to check if `total` right or not and it's right maybe I used it in php code wrong is that right: `$total= $_POST['total']`

Comment: That looks right to me

Comment: @HazemBehairy so which `total` variable is undefined, precisely? The JS one or the PHP one? It's not clear, from your description.

Comment: @ADyson the PHP one should I use `isset` function before `$_POST['total']`

Comment: @HazemBehairy Yes you should, for safety. But, if you've configured the code correctly as per this answer then the field _shouldn't_ be empty, as long as the parseFloat succeeded (but even then it might send the NaN I think, not sure without testing).

Comment: Just show us a `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I just figured that I have a syntax error :D. Thanks bro this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the assist @ADyson